# Open SSL / Https url through selenium-rc

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

**Please suggest me, how to open the SSL urls using selenium-rc?**

Answer (score 0):

You can open them exactly how you open non-SSL URL's.
See the Selenium RC [documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#programming-your-test)

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium attribute trustallSSLCertificates to handle SSL certificate error

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox you should add and save an exception for your https-URL to avoid certificate warning